# How to run `preLaunchTask` in the Python Debug Console in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to run a `preLaunchTask` called `saml2aws` in the `Python Debug Console` in order to set AWS-specific environment variables needed by some tests.

The problem I'm facing is that the `preLaunchTask` is executed in a new terminal called `saml2aws`, different from the `Python Debug Console`, so that the tests cannot see them in their environment.

How can I make VS Code execute the `preLaunchTask` in a specific terminal?

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks

launch.json:

```
...
{
  "name": "tunnel:redis:dim:test",
  "type": "python",
  "request": "launch",
  "module": "pytest",
  "args": ["app/tests_integration/test_system.py::test_dim_redis_tunnel"],
  "console": "integratedTerminal",
  "env": {
    "DO_TUNNEL": "true",
    "dim_NAMESPACE": "dim-test",
  },
  "preLaunchTask": "saml2aws"
},
...
```

tasks.json:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
  // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "saml2aws",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "eval $(saml2aws script)",
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
        "panel": "shared",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]